# This PHP SQL wont get the correct output

Tags: php, sql

this PHP code, is supposed to get the amount of mails received by the user (internal mail system). It works fine, until i add the "AND deleted = '0'" in the SQL code below. And in the SQL Table, all mails is set to "0" in the deleted input.

```
$user = $get2['username'];

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mailbox WHERE sender = '$user' AND deleted = '0' ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "". $row['COUNT(*)']. "";
     }
} else {
     echo "0";
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: Are you sure that there is a string `'0'`, not simple zero `0`?

Comment: i just tried it out, it doesnt seem to work either.

Comment: change `SELECT COUNT(*)` to `SELECT COUNT(*) cnt` and `$row['COUNT(*)']` to `$row['cnt']`  the RDBMS creates an alias for count(*) when it runs which is different than count(*)

Comment: Not related, but a `COUNT` like this will only give you one row so you don't need to sort it. Unless you add a `GROUP BY`, then you can get more results.

Comment: I dont get it, somehow it only works without the "AND deleted = '0'".

Comment: `var_dump($row)`, make sure that you're using the the correct array key...

Comment: Replace AND deleted = '0' with AND deleted = 0. Check if it works else paste the exact error you are getting

Comment: @ThomasBangThomasGaming Define "not working". Do you get an error? If so, what error do you see? If it's not an error, post what is the output and what is the expected output? Also, post a sample of the data.

Comment: The expedted output, is the amount of rows, where the sender is the user, and the deleted is equal to zero (if the user hasnt deleted the mail). btw. i see not error, tried to change the "0" in the else, wich it showed the result of..

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the output. http://i.imgur.com/Ix2Fomh.png

Comment: Do you have a column called `deleted`? You need to add some error checking to your database connection and queries and/or look in your error logs for more detailed output about why your query isn't working.

Comment: Yes imgur.com/a/yHfQ1 and all rows has the deleted set to 0 and only that.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code..

```
 `$user = $get2['username']`;
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNTS FROM mailbox WHERE sender = '$user' AND deleted = '0' ORDER BY id DESC";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
         // output data of each row
         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "". $row['COUNTS']. "";
         }
    } else {
         echo "0";
    }

    $conn->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Already solved.
Did not connect properly to the database which i was sure it did.

Answer (score 0):

> You have written query with just a little mistake.
>   So please try following query :

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS counted FROM mailbox WHERE sender = '$user' AND deleted = '0' ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "". $row['counted']. "";
     }

} else {
     echo "Sorry";
}

$conn->close();
```

**I hope this will work.**

Answer (score -1):

Change `AND deleted = '0' ORDER BY` to `AND deleted = 0 ORDER BY`

I'm guessing that the column DELETED is some sort of number data format instead of a string format.

Comment: mysql will convert as necessary, and `1 = '1'` comes out as true in normal mysql modes of operation.

Comment: @ThomasBangThomasGaming You should optimize your table first, varchar is not very appropriate to store a flag for your "deleted" field. You should use the boolean type or the tinyint type.